# Different CSS behaviours on HTML divs

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of problems with my CSS.
First off, I'm trying to get two adjacent boxes to stay put in the middle of the webpage. Although the right box (green text) works perfectly fine, the left box not only goes out of bounds of the window, it also won't position itself correctly.

I tried playing around with float right and left to no avail as well as the positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/XEUbc/1522/

I've been fiddling around the CSS so there might be some useless CSS bits and pieces.

```
.game {


/*  width: 50%;*/
color: orange;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
position:relative;
/*float:left;*/
top:35px;
right:50%;
bottom:0;
max-width:600px;
min-width:500px;
margin:70px 20px 20px 20px;
overflow-y:auto;
/*overflow-x:hidden;*/
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14)
}

.equation{
/*position: fixed;

/*width: 50%;*/
/*float:right;*/
/*float:right;*/
color: green;   
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
position:relative;
top:35px;
left:50%;
/*right:0;*/
bottom:0;
max-width:600px;
min-width:500px;
margin:70px 20px 20px 20px;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
box-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.14)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, thats a lot of css for a single element.

You could try to set float left for both right and left divs and wrap them in a container, set width for each to get them to go beside one another.

Or you could set `display:inline-block` and set `vertical-align:top` to both divs to get them to be beside one another.

Also, i would suggest you use percentages or `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto`, to align your divs/set margins if not it would not look nice with the content and text on resize.

Comment: The reason why your divs occupy only the left side, is because you need to add: margin-left:auto;, margin-right:auto, to both divs to get them to stay in the centre of your wrapper/body. Make sure your display is block too so it will work and give them widths.

Answer (score 0):

Your margins are pushing the boxes around - `relative` position keeps the elements in the flow of the document. In other words, two elements can't occupy the same exact space if they're relatively positioned with one another, which includes margins.

A much simpler implementation would be to create a wrapper `div` and then use `display: table` and `table-cell` to align the two content boxes and have them the same size.

Your HTML would be something like...

```
<div id="wrapper>
  <div class="game">
    <p>Some content here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="equation">
    <p>More content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS...

```
#wrapper {
    display:table;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#wrapper > div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;  /* this just shows where the cells are */
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XEUbc/1524/)

It's much cleaner and is more easy to manage the inline content without using tricky float positioning. Of course, you can style each cell as you were originally with shadows, etc. This is just to get you on the right track.

Comment: I tried using your css and bizarrely enough, even though the code works on fiddle, it doesn't work when I try to run it locally on chrome. The Divs end up both occupying the left side of the window instead of sharing the center like the fiddle.

Comment: You might have other CSS in there that is moving the divs around. You got rid of all your original code, right?